# Adding data dimensions to ChartJS stacked bar chart

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart with an hour bucket on the x-axis (9am, 10am, 11am, ...) and a count on the y-axis.  The data I want grouped by day (Monday, Tuesday,...) and person (Alice, Bob) to look something like this:
[image]
Monday, Tuesday, Bob, Alice should be selectable options (hide/show), but no labels on the bars - (that's just to clarify the data).

Ideally, I'd like to specify my data something like:

```js
const labels = ['9am','10am','11am','12pm'];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Monday',
      data: [{x:'9am',person:'Bob',y:7},{x:'10am',person:'Bob',y:6},{x:'11am',person:'Bob',y:5},{x:'12pm',y:4},{x:'9am',person:'Alice',y:7},{x:'10am',person:'Alice',y:6},{x:'11am',person:'Alice',y:5},{x:'12pm',y:4}],
      stack: data.x,
    },
    {
      label: 'Tuesday',
      data: [{x:'9am',person:'Bob',y:7},{x:'10am',person:'Bob',y:6},{x:'11am',person:'Bob',y:5},{x:'12pm',y:4},{x:'9am',person:'Alice',y:7},{x:'10am',person:'Alice',y:6},{x:'11am',person:'Alice',y:5},{x:'12pm',y:4}],
    }
  ]
};
```

or (EDIT 1)

```js
const labels = ['9am','10am','11am','12pm'];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Bob',
      data: [{x:'9am',day:'Monday',y:7},{x:'10am',day:'Monday',y:6},{x:'11am',day:'Monday',y:5},{x:'12pm', day:'Monday', y:4},{x:'9am',day:'Tuesday',y:7},{x:'10am',day:'Tuesday',y:6},{x:'11am',day:'Tuesday',y:5},{x:'12pm',day:'Tuesday',y:4}],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
    {
      label: 'Alice',
      data: [{x:'9am',day:'Monday',y:7},{x:'10am',day:'Monday',y:6},{x:'11am',day:'Monday',y:5},{x:'12pm',day:'Monday',y:4},{x:'9am',day:'Tuesday',y:7},{x:'10am',day:'Tuesday',y:6},{x:'11am',day:'Tuesday',y:5},{x:'12pm',day:'Tuesday',y:4}],
      backgroundColor:'amber';
    }
  ]
};
```

and have the stack specified by some data item, like 'data.day'.

Config I've tried:

```js
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```js
const labels = ['9am','10am','11am','12pm'];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Bob-Monday',
      data: [{x:'9am',y:7},{x:'10am',y:6},{x:'11am',y:5},{x:'12pm',y:4}],
      stack: 'Monday',
    },
    {
      label: 'Alice-Monday',
      data: [{x:'9am',y:7},{x:'10am',y:8},{x:'11am',y:10},{x:'12pm',y:9}],
      stack: 'Monday',
    },
    {
      label: 'Bob-Tue',
      data: [{x:'9am',y:7},{x:'10am',y:6},{x:'11am',y:4},{x:'12pm',y:3}],
      stack: 'Tue',
    },
    {
      label: 'Alice-Tue',
      data: [{x:'9am',y:7},{x:'10am',y:8},{x:'11am',y:10},{x:'12pm',y:9}],
      stack: 'Tue',
    }
  ]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
};
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: The code snippet seems to do exactly what you say you want to achieve. What's missing?

Comment: @kikon I don't want ["Bob-Monday", "Alice-Monday", "Bob-Tuesday", "Alice-Tuesday"]; I'm looking for ["Bob", "Alice", "Monday", "Tuesday"] where I can show/hide the person and day.

Comment: So, the values and colors of the bars should be the same as in the snippet, but you want to be able to select/unselect from the legend directly all Bob's bars, all Alice's bars, all Monday bars and all Tue bars?

Comment: @kikon That's right, but the color for Bob should always be blue, Alice should be amber (for example).

Comment: Then there will be no color distinction between Monday and Tuesday

Comment: @kikon yes, just realized that. Maybe an outline color for the day or a day label?

Comment: Here's a [possible interpretation](https://jsfiddle.net/ykegdjz8/) of a custom legend where a legend item gets data and interacts with multiple datasets. Please let me know if it's OK

Comment: @kikon That works well, but I'm wondering how it will work with a variable number of people and days? There could be up to about 20 people and 7 days. Is it possible for it to take information from the data as in EDIT 1 example in my question? The data can be in any format, so it's ok to change it to make the javascript easier. Also, can the days selection legend be in a separate line (div?) from the names?

Comment: Yes, sure. I'll write that up as an answer later. Not sure about controlling where the legend gets split in two lines, I'll check if it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the main feature of your problem appears to be the fact that the data is indexed by two variables, `person` and `day` (besides the standard x-axis variation `hour`) and since you already suggested restructuring the data in a non-chart.js format, but one
that makes sense for the data, I'd
recommend to structure your data on a two level format (`dataset2d` in the example below) and use a [custom plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html)
that would preprocess the data in
its [`beforeInit`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#chart-initialization)
handler. This will allow setting options either at the level of an item of `datasets2d` or at the level of an `datasets` item. Note: formally, the data is three dimensional,
but since `hour` is the variable represented on the x axis,
we'll focus on the two *remaining* variables.

The main difficulty of the problem consists in the
requirement for custom legend items. Fortunately,
chart.js is flexible with respect to
[legend label configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)
allowing a custom legend or canvas to be
provided as [`pointStyle`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface),
while the effect of selection and deselection of
legend items can be perfectly controlled through
the customizable [legend click handler](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#custom-on-click-actions).

The plugin `datasets2d` in the code snippet below,
does first a simple mapping of the 2d data to a
one dimensional standard dataset with stacks
corresponding to the values of the inner `label`.
Then, it employs the legend customization features
noted above to achieve the desired legend item
form and functionality.

```js
const labels = ['9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm'];
const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets2d: [
        {
            label: 'Bob',
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Monday',
                    data: [{x: '9am', y: 7}, {x: '10am', y: 6}, {x: '11am', y: 5}, {x: '12pm', y: 4}],
                    // or just data: [7, 6, 5, 4],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Tuesday',
                    data: [{x: '9am', y: 7}, {x: '10am', y: 6}, {x: '11am', y: 4}, {x: '12pm', y: 3}],
                    // or just data: [7, 6, 4, 3]
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Alice',
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Monday',
                    data: [{x: '9am', y: 7}, {x: '10am', y: 8}, {x: '11am', y: 10}, {x: '12pm', y: 9}],
                    // or just data: [7, 8, 10, 9],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.7)'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Tuesday',
                    data: [{x: '9am', y: 7}, {x: '10am', y: 8}, {x: '11am', y: 10}, {x: '12pm', y: 9}],
                    // or just data: [7, 8, 10, 9]
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const pluginDatasets2d = {
    id: 'datasets2d',

    _objMinusKeys(obj, minusKeys = []){
        return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => !minusKeys.includes(key)));
    },

    _canvasMultiColor(width, height, colors, horizontal){
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const nColors = colors.length, frac = 1 / nColors;
        const grad = horizontal ? ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, width, 0) : ctx.createLinearGradient(0, height, 0, 0);
        grad.addColorStop(0, colors[0]);
        for(let iColor = 1; iColor < nColors; iColor++){
            grad.addColorStop(iColor * frac, colors[iColor - 1]);
            grad.addColorStop(iColor * frac, colors[iColor]);
        }
        grad.addColorStop(1, colors[nColors - 1]);
        ctx.fillStyle = grad;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        return canvas;
    },

    _generateLegendLabel(text, idx, colors, legendPointWidth, hidden, horizontal = true){
        const legendPointHeight = legendPointWidth / 2;
        return {
            text: text,
            datasetIndex: idx,
            fillStyle: '#fff', // not used
            fontColor: '#000',
            hidden: hidden,
            lineCap: 0, // not used
            lineDash: [], // not used
            lineDashOffset: 0, // not used
            lineJoin: 0, // not used
            lineWidth: 0, // not used
            strokeStyle: '#fff', // not used
            pointStyle: this._canvasMultiColor(
                legendPointWidth, legendPointHeight, colors, horizontal),
            rotation: 0
        }
    },

    onLegendClick(e, legendItem, legend){
        const _computeDatasetsToBeHidden = function(legendIndicesDisabled){
                const datasetsHidden = [];
                for(const legendIndex of legendIndicesDisabled){
                    for(const index of legend.legendItems[legendIndex].datasetIndex){
                        if(!datasetsHidden.includes(index)){
                            datasetsHidden.push(index);
                        }
                    }
                }
                datasetsHidden.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
                return datasetsHidden;
            },

            _computeLegendIndicesToBeDisabled = function(datasetsHidden){
                const legendIndicesDisabled = [];
                legend.legendItems.forEach((legendItem, legendIndex) => {
                    const datasetIndices = legendItem.datasetIndex;
                    if(datasetIndices.reduce((s, index) => s && datasetsHidden.includes(index), true)){
                        legendIndicesDisabled.push(legendIndex);
                    }
                });
                return legendIndicesDisabled;
            };

        const legendIndex = legend.legendItems.indexOf(legendItem);
        let legendIndicesDisabled1 = legend.legendItems.map(
            (legendItem, legendIndex) => !legendItem.hidden ? null : legendIndex).filter(x=>x!==null);

        let datasetsHidden1 = _computeDatasetsToBeHidden(legendIndicesDisabled1);
        const clickToEnable = legendIndicesDisabled1.includes(legendIndex);
        let legendIndicesDisabled =  clickToEnable ?
            legendIndicesDisabled1.filter(legendIndex1 => legendIndex1 !== legendIndex) :
            legendIndicesDisabled1.concat(legendIndex).sort((a,b)=>a-b);
        let datasetsHidden = _computeDatasetsToBeHidden(legendIndicesDisabled);

        if(datasetsHidden.length === datasetsHidden1.length && clickToEnable){
            // if the click makes no difference in datasets status (maintaining all other legend items status)
            datasetsHidden1 = datasetsHidden.filter(datasetIdx => !legendItem.datasetIndex.includes(datasetIdx));
            // then show/hide clicked item datasets and update the other legend items
            let kSafe = 0;
            while(datasetsHidden1.length !== datasetsHidden.length && kSafe++<10){
                datasetsHidden = datasetsHidden1;
                legendIndicesDisabled = _computeLegendIndicesToBeDisabled(datasetsHidden);
                datasetsHidden1 = _computeDatasetsToBeHidden(legendIndicesDisabled);
            }
        }
        else{
            legendIndicesDisabled = _computeLegendIndicesToBeDisabled(datasetsHidden);
        }


        const chart = legend.chart;
        for(let datasetIndex = 0; datasetIndex < chart.data.datasets.length; datasetIndex++){
            chart.setDatasetVisibility(datasetIndex, !datasetsHidden.includes(datasetIndex));
        }
        chart.update();
        legend.legendItems.forEach((legendItem, legendIndex) => {
            legendItem.hidden = legendIndicesDisabled.includes(legendIndex);
        })
    },

    // make closure with plugin, to be able to call other functions of the plugin
    generateLabelsGen(plugin){
        return function(chart){
            const height = chart.legend.height;
            if(!height) return;

            const {stacks, labels, orderedStacks, orderedLabels} = chart._metasets.reduce(
                ({stacks, labels, orderedLabels, orderedStacks}, _meta, i) => {
                    const stack = _meta.stack,
                        label = _meta.label.replace(new RegExp(' \- ' + stack + '$'), '');
                    if(!stacks[stack]){
                        stacks[stack] = [i];
                        orderedStacks.push(stack);
                    }
                    else{
                        stacks[stack].push(i);
                    }
                    if(!labels[label]){
                        labels[label] = [i];
                        orderedLabels.push(label);
                    }
                    else{
                        labels[label].push(i);
                    }
                    return ({stacks, labels, orderedLabels, orderedStacks});
                }, {labels: {}, stacks: {}, orderedLabels: [], orderedStacks: []});
            const colorForMetaset =
                    idx => chart.getDatasetMeta(idx)._dataset.backgroundColor
                        || 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5)',
                colorsForMetasets = a => a.map(colorForMetaset),
                pointStyleWidth = chart.legend.options.labels.pointStyleWidth;

            if(chart.legend.legendItems){
                return orderedLabels.map(
                    label => plugin._generateLegendLabel(label, labels[label],
                        colorsForMetasets(labels[label]),
                        pointStyleWidth || 40, chart.legend.legendItems[0]?.hidden)
                ).concat(orderedStacks.map(
                    stack => plugin._generateLegendLabel(stack, stacks[stack],
                        colorsForMetasets(stacks[stack]),
                        pointStyleWidth || 40, chart.legend.legendItems[0]?.hidden, false)
                ));
            }
        }
    },

    beforeInit(chart){
        const datasets2d = chart.config.data.datasets2d;
        const datasetsNewObj = {}, optionsNewObj = {};
        for(const dataset2d of datasets2d){
            const label = dataset2d.label || '',
                // take options from dataset2d
                optionsTop = this._objMinusKeys(dataset2d, ['label', 'datasets']);
            for(const dataset of dataset2d.datasets){
                const innerLabel = dataset.label || '',
                    newLabel = label + ' - ' + innerLabel;
                optionsNewObj[newLabel] = {
                    ...optionsTop,
                    // combine with options from dataset
                    ...this._objMinusKeys(dataset, ['label', 'data']),
                    stack: innerLabel
                };
                datasetsNewObj[newLabel] = [];
                for(const dataItem of dataset.data){
                    datasetsNewObj[newLabel].push(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }
        const datasetsNew = Object.entries(datasetsNewObj).map(
            ([label, data]) => ({data, label, ...optionsNewObj[label]})
        );
        chart.config.data.datasets = datasetsNew;

        chart.legend.options.labels.usePointStyle = true;
        chart.legend.options.labels.pointStyleWidth = chart.legend.options.labels.boxWidth;

        chart.legend.options.labels.generateLabels = this.generateLabelsGen(this);
        chart.legend.options.onClick = this.onLegendClick;
    }
};


const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    plugins: [
        pluginDatasets2d
    ],
    options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
            },
            legend: {
                //position: "right"
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true,
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        }
    }
};
new Chart('myChart', config);
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 60vh">
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4"></script>
```

[Here's a version](https://jsfiddle.net/okgcv4Ls/)
with multiple persons and days; adding or removing
a day or a person is as simple as changing the
contents of the first two arrays.

Comment: When deselecting a day or name, it deselects everything else.

Comment: Please give me the exact  sequence of selections/deselections that doesn't work. I programmed it specifically to recompute selections *consistently* each time, noting that *selections are not fully independent of each other* - for instance if you deselect Bob and deselect Alice, then it should automatically deselect Monday and Tuesday because there's nothing shown. If then with nothing selected you select Monday then it should automatically select Bob and Alice, because they have bars shown.

Comment: Consistence means that a legend item is unselected if and only if all of the bars related to that item are hidden (which is exactly what happens if only one item is unselected).

Comment: To further explain this sequence: `initial state` -> `unselect Bob` -> `unselect Alice` (==> all unselected, all bars hidden) -> `select Monday`. After that your are left with Bob, Alice and Monday selected and Tuesday unselected. And the bars are exactly the same state as if you would have done `initial state` ->  `unselect Tuesday`. That is, the legend items state (selected or unselected) and  bars state (shown or hidden) are always matched the same way, regardless of the order you click the legend items.

Comment: Initially, all data is selected (this is fine). Sequence: unselect Bob -> unselect Monday -> select Monday ==> Bob is also selected, should remain unselected.

Comment: I updated the plugin code to reduce the number of cases where changing the state of a legend item results in changes to other items.